# i want to dynamically retrieve rows from table based on my selection.i tried this code

Tags: java

//Im trying to dynamically retrieve rows from table based on my selection. //and i tried this code, getting that variable nname not used (i want to retrieve rows dynamically according to my choice, so how should i write query)

```
*String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trial";
        String uname = "root";
        String paswd = "admin";

        System.out.println("Type a name");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String nname = br.readLine();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, paswd);
            Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();
            String query = "select *from parent  WHERE name = 'br.nname'";
            ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(query);*
```

Comment: And what is not working ?

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: WHERE name = 'br.nname' should be "WHERE name = 'nname'"

Comment: @isaace That's also wrong.

Comment: I downvoted due to the lack of a question, and [for being unresponsive to comments](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive). You need to [include a helpful problem statement](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) as well as an actual question.

Comment: Im trying to dynamically retrieve rows from table based on my selection. //and i tried this codeIm trying to dynamically retrieve rows from table based on my selection. And i coded, getting that the variable nname not used but im using in query. And not getting the output

Comment: Im trying to dynamically retrieve rows from table based on my selection. //and i tried this code. And i coded, getting that the variable nname not used but im using in query. And not getting the output. (i want to retrieve rows dynamically according to my choice, so how should i write query)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are building your query using a variable name instead of the variable's value. query should probably be:

```
String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM parent WHERE name='%s'", nname);
```

Comment: for this code getting unknown format coversion exception

Comment: My bad, should have been "%s", fixed the code above.  Hope that works.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @EJoshuaS, Very true is best to use some kind of prepared statement but is outside of the scope of the question.